# How to change the value of a tables attribute using LINQ/LAMBDA?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have an order table and an orderStatus table, their relationship is as seen below:

[image]

I want to be able to change 'StatusID' to the value 2, of a specific order (i am able to get the specific order ID, and have loaded it into an integer variable) using a lambda expression within an action result - would there be any easy way of doing this?

So far i have tried:

```
//get specific order ID
int currentOrderId = newConfirmedOrderLine.OrderID;

//-----
Order statusChange = new Order();
statusChange.OrderStatus.StatusID = 2;
DBAccessor.SaveChanges();
```

I am new to linq and lambda, so any explanation with an answer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DBAccessor` is a DbContext then this could/should work. You need to load the `Order` entity that you want to change from the `DBAccessor.Order` DbSet, change it by setting a property, and then call SaveChanges.

```
var orderStatus = DBAccessor.OrderStatus.First(x => x.StatusID == 2);
var order = DBAccessor.Order.Find(currentOrderId);
order.OrderStatus = orderStatus;
DBAccessor.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks man. Although on the first line, x.Status needs to be x.StatusID. Appreciate the help.